# Narrowing Shield UI ASP.NET Chart database rows to unique

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I am visualizing a database with a Shield UI ASP Chart. The case with my data is that the rows are not unique. For instance I have some categories and different values for them. How can I sum up the values from the rows and add them to the appropriate categories?
Is there a way to bind this property :

```
<shield:ChartAxisX CategoricalValues="Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4">
</shield:ChartAxisX>
```

to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am understanding correct you need to find out how many the unique rows for one field are and than sum up another field among these categories.

However this is what you shall do with an SQL query and not trying to pass raw data to a chart. Shield UI ASP charts that have categories need to receive the data per category and display it. At least charts are intended for seamless and fast graphical data representation.